# How can I mock the instantiation of a Class

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, kafka-python

I can't seem to figure out how to mock the instantiation of a class, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I am trying to do:

I would like to test the method `ClassA.some_method()` and specifically if `kafka_producer.flush()` was called, however I don't want `KafkaProducer` to be instantiated because it makes some requests which fail in my test environment.

```py
class ClassA:

    def some_method(self):

        # Do some stuff ...
        kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(...)
        # Do some more stuff ...
        kafka_producer.flush()
```

I have tried to use `mock.patch` as follows but the requests are still made and fail before getting to the relevant test part:

```
with mock.patch.object(kafka, "KafkaProducer", autospec=True) as kafka_producer:
    class_a.some_method()
    kafka_producer.assert_called()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use an object there which has a flush method and inject that as a dependency. Use the real object in prod, and a fake/mock object in test

Comment: I believe you'd have to patch the `KafkaProducer` in your module, not in the `kafka` library. I imagine your `ClassA` lives in a file (let's call it `my_thingy.py`) where you also do `from kafka import KafkaProducer`, right? Can you try patching `mock.patch.object(my_thingy, "KafkaProducer", autospec=True)` ?

Comment: Ideally don't construct the object within `some_method`. Provide it as a dependency to the `ClassA` constructor. That will allow injecting the dependency during tests without the need for `mock.patch` at all. I generally consider `mock.patch` to be an anti-pattern when used anywhere outside of mocking main method startup, as it promotes creating inflexible code which is highly susceptible to test failures during simple refactorings.

Comment: @flakes Or at the very least, provide a factory that can be used to construct the object. `def some_method(self, factory=KafkaProducer): kafka_producer = factory(...); ...`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to patch `KafkaProducer` at the place where it is used, as already suggested in the comments

Here is a full source code

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from path.to.class_a import ClassA

def test_flush_was_called():
    with patch('path.to.class_a.KafkaProducer') as mock_kafka_producer:
        sut = ClassA()

        sut.some_method()

        # Assert that class instance was created
        mock_kafka_producer.assert_called_once()


        # Assert that flush was called
        mock_kafka_instance = mock_kafka_producer.return_value
        mock_kafka_instance.flush.assert_called_once()
```

If you have difficulties, the following patch should also work:

```py
with patch(f'{ClassA.__module__}.KafkaProducer') as mock_kafka_producer:
```

If you prefer `patch.object` syntax:

```
...

import path.to.class_a

def test_flush_was_called():
      with patch.object(path.to.class_a, 'KafkaProducer', autospec=True) as mock_kafka_producer:
          ...
```

Comment: The part about `path.to.class_a.KafkaProducer` does not look right to me, and this answer was not accepted, so I'm not sure if this actually works :/